# How to refer to the original position of a list item when text filter is enabled?

Tags: android, listview, filter

When I use edit text to filter the items, the list positions get all messed up and the items no longer call the proper intent. Any help is appreciated

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String mName = filteredValues.get(position).getName().toString();
        String mWeb = filteredValues.get(position).getWebsite().toString();

        Intent openDetails = new Intent(Test.this, ResourceDetails.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();            
        b.putString("name", mName);
        b.putString("web", mWeb);
        openDetails.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(openDetails);                 
    }
});

private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher(){
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
};
```

Comment: why don't you put the ID you need in the row Tag and simply get it with Integer id = (Integer)view.getTag();

Comment: I haven't tried that..I will try it now..thanks

Comment: Are you using an ArrayAdapter with a customized #getView?

Answer (score 2):

```
 flashsearchList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Integer temp=flashSearchNameMap.get(adapter.getItem(position));

            navigateSearch(temp); 



        }
    });
```

(adapter.getItem(position) will return you the exact list name and in flashSearchNameMap i have stored names and position at beginning from oncreate before applying filtering.So you can get exact position by this

Answer (score 2):

if you use `ViewHolder` in `Adapter` just define a realPosition variable in holder class and set it in YourAdapter.getView

and in listClick Listener

```
 ContactAdapter.ViewHolder holder = (YourAdapter.ViewHolder) view.getTag();
 holder.realPosition
```

Answer (score 1):

The item position is not reliable when using lists. I recommend you to use `view.setTag(Object)` to assign an identifier to each item when attaching the content.  This could be a number, string or anything. Then you can just access it with `view.getTag()` inside the click listener.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a custom bean object to store your name & website values and an `ArrayAdapter` to show them in your `ListView`, like so

```
public class NamedLink {
    final String mName;
    final String mWebsite; 
    public NamedLink(String name, String website) {
        mName = name;
        mWebsite = website;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return mName;
    }
}
```

With an adapter, defined something like this:

```
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<NamedLink>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, mLinks) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(WhateverYourActivityIsNamed.this).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null);
            }
            NamedLink link = getItem(position);
            // This probably deserves a ViewHolder
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(link.getName());
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(link.getWebsite());
            return convertView;
        }
    };
```

When you filter the array adapter it will match against the beans `#toString()`, which in this case returns the name. When filtered, the array adapter maintains a properly indexed copy of your list of beans internally - i.e. you can use the position you get in the click listener like this:

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // getItemAtPosition() will return a NamedLink from the filtered
            // list maintained inside the ArrayAdapter
            NamedLink link = (NamedLink) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent openDetails = new Intent(Test.this, ResourceDetails.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();            
            b.putString("name", link.getName());
            b.putString("web", link.getWebsite());
            openDetails.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(openDetails);  
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am amazed he didn't accept it as an answer , wonder-boy :) keep up the good work.! i don't have enough points but when i will get, definitely i will try my best to bounty this answer.!