# How to get the correct position in listview when setTextFilterEnabled is enable?

Tags: android, listview, filter

I'm trying to get the correct position in the listview when i clicked one item on it. I enable the setTextFilterEnabled. Here is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

.....

//get files
    getfile(root);

adapter = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mylist));
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.view);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

.....

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            String pdfPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + fileList.get(position).getName();


            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("location_of_file", pdfPath);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


.....
```

Here is my ArrayList get the files

```
public ArrayList<File> getfile(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                getfile(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".pdf"))

                {
                    fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

This is where is used the filtering

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                              int count) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //when input text is changed hide list
    }

};
```

In my listview onClickListener it always give me the wrong position and got the wrong path of file.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: thank you so much @MikeM. !

Comment: No problem. If that post answered your question, you should be able to mark it as helpful to close out your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Replace `String pdfPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + fileList.get(position).getName();`

With `String pdfPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + ((File)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)).getName();`

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/19926676/3977935

Comment: I cannot be use `.getName()` in getItem().

Comment: @KairiSan updated my answer. Check now

Comment: My application crashes when I clicked an item. :(

Comment: @KairiSan Cant help without seeing the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

This is based on Mike's comment on my question.

changed

`fileList.get(position).getName()`

to

`parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);`

I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926517/listview-custom-filter-gives-wrong-item-selected-when-filtered-android)